# Select object with JQuery selector by data attribute with multiple value

Tags: jquery, selector

I need to select div by data, with multiple data value.

```
<div data-name='["ab","abcd","abcdf"]' />

$("div[data-name*='ab']")
```

But this solution selects all divs that contain 'ab'.
I need to select only divs that contain only 'ab'.

EDIT: the best solution:

```
<div data-name='["ab","abcd","abcdf"]' />

$("div[data-name*='ab\"']")
```

Comment: ok then try `$(div[data-name*='"ab"'])`

Answer (score 3):

It's probably best to `.filter` the list:

```
$('div[data-name]').filter(function() {
   return $.inArray("ab", $(this).data('name')) >= 0
});
```

i.e. select any `div` with a `data-name` attribute, and then explicitly pick out those whose array value contains the desired element.

Comment: +1. was about to paste a asolution like this :-) , just found out that `$(this).data('name')` ia already an array :-)

Comment: ? `var a=$('div').eq(0).data('name');
alert({}.toString.apply(a)) //Array
`

Comment: (all im saying is that $(this).data('name') in this case is a pure JS  array)

Comment: Hmm, you're right, but for some reason `.indexOf` wasn't working...  but does now.   Weird.  In any event, `$.inArray` is more portable.

Comment: p.s. for the data to be an array it _must_ be in proper JSON syntax.  If you use the wrong style of quotes it fails.

Comment: @RoyiNamir your jsbin needs `Array.prototype.indexOf.apply(a, [1])`

Comment: so if this `alert(Array.prototype.indexOf.apply(a,[1]))` does work  , why your code didnt work ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir I probably made a mistake, but I'm not sure what it was.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div data-name='["ab","abcd","abcdf"]' />
<div data-name='["b","abcd","abcdf"]' />
<div data-name='["v","abcd","abcdf"]' />
<div data-name='' />
<div />
```

Jquery:

```
var  divList = [];
divList = $('div').filter(function() {
    if($(this).data('name') != "")
   return $.inArray("ab", $(this).data('name')) >= 0
});
alert(divList.length)
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/X8c9Z/6/)

Comment: Why convert the jQuery object into a native array?

Comment: @Alnitak: Yes you are right, it already a array object. Thank you to update me for my silly mistake  :)